# create time series object for all variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I want to create a time series object for all variables. If I use only one variable, it is simple

```
w=ts(mydat$x1,frequency = 12,start=c(2015,1))
```

but I have many variables.

Here part of it.

```
    mydat=structure(list(date = structure(c(3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("apr-15", 
"feb-15", "jan-15", "jul15", "jun-15", "march-15", "may-15"), class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(653411L, 620453L, 742567L, 578548L, 720100L, 553740L, 
    588145L), x2 = c(242108L, 210841L, 255046L, 185243L, 257159L, 
    182594L, 246051L), x3 = c(234394L, 289563L, 341791L, 293608L, 
    306807L, 285190L, 279252L), x4 = c(309228L, 226175L, 292387L, 
    183745L, 223322L, 161218L, 201499L)), .Names = c("date", 
"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

How can I create a time series object in my dataset for next analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply provide all the columns you wish:

```
myts <- stats::ts(mydat[,-1], frequency = 12, start = c(2015,1))
> myts
             x1     x2     x3     x4
Jan 2015 653411 242108 234394 309228
Feb 2015 620453 210841 289563 226175
Mar 2015 742567 255046 341791 292387
Apr 2015 578548 185243 293608 183745
May 2015 720100 257159 306807 223322
Jun 2015 553740 182594 285190 161218
Jul 2015 588145 246051 279252 201499
```